cleveref issue with label using polyglossia
Why is this giving me the error
./crefstar.tex:42: Undefined control sequence.
\@templabel ->\xpg 
                   _select_default_fontfamily:n {english}\fontseries {m}\sel...
l.42 As in \cref*{pfcasecaseii}
                               , and more.

when I try to compile with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? (The error occurs on the second run, apparently when processing the label for the \cref*.)
The MWE source:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\setotherlanguages{french,german,polish,russian}  
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}  
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}

\newlist{romcases}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[romcases,1]{%
    label=\sffamily{Case (\roman*):},
    ref=\normalfont{(\roman*)},
    wide,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt
}

\crefname{romcasesi}{Case}{Cases}
\Crefname{romcasesi}{Case}{Cases}

\begin{document}

Let $J$ be a nonempty interval.

\begin{romcases}

\item
$J$ has both a lower bound and an upper bound. Blah-blah

\item\label{pfcasecaseii}% ii
$J$ has a lower bound but not an upper bound. In this case, etc.

\item
$J$ has an upper bound but not a lower bound. 
As in \cref*{pfcasecaseii}, and more.

\end{romcases}

\end{document}

The error disappears if I comment out the fontenc line and the subsequent three polyglossia-related lines

never load fontenc with a unicode engine. and you need to config fonts for polyglossia.

@cfr: (1) Don't I need fontenc to get the T2A encoding for Russian? (2) What do you mean by "config[ure] fonts for polyglossia"?

you ought not use the T2A encoding with a unicode engine. so, yes, to get T2A, you need fontenc but, no, you should not use fontenc with a unicode engine.

assuming your default font doesn't offer Cyrillic, you need to set up a font either per-script or per-language, for those which TG Termes doesn't support. (I didn't check what the font supports.)

Off-topic: Do you really need the : (colon) characters at the end of each numbered case? IMNSHO, the colons serve no discernible typographical purpose.

Off-topic: \sffamily and \normalfont aren't commands taking an argument. You're lucky that the label is typeset in a group; also \normalfont makes no sense in ref. The correct syntax would be label=\normalfont\sffamily Case (\roman*): and ref=Case (roman*)

which hyperref version do you have?

@egreg - Setting ref=Case (roman*) will clash with cleveref's work in case a \cref instruction has more than one romcasesi-type argument. ref=(roman*) avoids this sort of clash. Actually, if it were up to me, I'd just set ref=\roman*, to further streamline the look of a cross-reference to multiple romancasesi objects.

@Mico You're right, I forgot to remove “Case ” (but I did it in my answer).

Don't load fontenc (or, for that matter, inputenc) when compiling your document under XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Instead, just use an OpenType font that provides all glyphs required for your document. Since TeX Gyre Termes is a Times Roman clone, I suggest you replace it with FreeSerif.
In addition, don't use the default sans-serif font (Latin Modern Sans), as it doesn't mesh well with Times Roman. Instead, I suggest that you run \setsansfont{FreeSans}.
With these changes in place and simplifying things a bit in the preamble, the cleveref-related problem takes care of itself.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

%%%% \usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc} % absolutely not

\usepackage{unicode-math} % this loads 'fontspec' automatically
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase} % are you sure about this?
\setmainfont{FreeSerif} % Times Roman clone that has Cyrillic glyphs
\setsansfont{FreeSans} % Better than Latin Modern Sans, for sure
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[math-style=ISO]

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\setotherlanguages{french,german,polish,russian}  

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}

\newlist{romcases}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[romcases,1]{%
      label=\textsf{Case (\roman*):},
      ref=(\roman*), % or maybe 'ref=\textup{(\roman*)}'?
      %wide,  % do you really want this?
      left=0pt,
      %itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt
      nosep
}

\crefname{romcasesi}{Case}{Cases}
%\Crefname{romcasesi}{Case}{Cases} % not needed

\begin{document}
Let $J$ be a nonempty interval.
\begin{romcases}
\item
$J$ has both a lower bound and an upper bound. 
Blah-blah

\item \label{pfcasecaseii} % ii
$J$ has a lower bound but not an upper bound. 
In this case, etc.

\item
$J$ has an upper bound but not a lower bound. 
As in \cref{pfcasecaseii}, etc.
\end{romcases}

\medskip\noindent
\begin{russian}
Привет, мир. Давным-давно и т. д.
\end{russian}

\end{document}


You don't want to load fontenc, but rather to define a font family that supports Cyrillic; polyglossia will silently substitute it when Russian is chosen. Since your main font is a Times clone, I use Tempora for Cyrillic. No TeX Gyre font supports Cyrillic characters.
An exception to my rule “packages first, then settings” is required because cleveref has limited support for polyglossia, so the languages have to be selected before loading cleveref (or passed also as an option thereto).
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc} % <--- NO!
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\setotherlanguages{french,german,polish,russian}  

\usepackage[
  nameinlink,
  noabbrev,
  capitalize,
]{cleveref}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{Tempora}

\newlist{romcases}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[romcases,1]{
  label=\sffamily Case (\roman*):,
  ref=(\roman*),
  wide,
  itemsep=0pt,
  topsep=0pt,
}

\crefname{romcasesi}{Case}{Cases}
\Crefname{romcasesi}{Case}{Cases}

\begin{document}

Let $J$ be a nonempty interval.

\begin{romcases}

\item
$J$ has both a lower bound and an upper bound. Blah-blah

\item\label{pfcasecaseii}% ii
$J$ has a lower bound but not an upper bound. In this case, etc.

\item
$J$ has an upper bound but not a lower bound. 
As in \cref*{pfcasecaseii}, and more.

\item \foreignlanguage{russian}{Это русский текст}

\end{romcases}

\end{document}


Beware that there's no support for Polish in cleveref.
